# Homepage template and url changed?

Tags: permalinks

when I activated the theme. it is only one page. the navbar links are Home #About #Services #Contact

the problem when I make template name on the frontpage

```
<?php

/* Template Name: front-page */ 
get_header(); ?>
```

then I created a page from the dashboard called Home

it added slug /home at the end of the url

so the website url differed because of this homepage template. it added the home slug the url. I need to remove /home slug. just want the same link without changing.

what should I do, please? to make template for homepage without changing the url of the website?

and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this article on how to create a static homepage in WordPress https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-static-front-page/

Comment: thanks for the comment. the article is very basic. I am asking about the url which has changed after automatically added home slug

Comment: After you select your Home page to display as a Front Page of the website, the slug must disappear

Comment: thanks. it worked now

Answer (score 0):

You can change /* Template Name: front-page */ and use page ID instead of a title.

Comment: How does that work? By change template name do you mean remove it? And by using the page ID you mean to select a page to be the static front page in admin site? How would you enter the page ID there - isn't it a dropdown of pages?